# How to write cypress locator for this dynamic button specific to the span element "Agile Fundamentals"

Tags: automation, cypress, relative-locators

I am new to cypress automation. I tried to use the following locator to click on the specific dynamic button.

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Agile Fundamentals').next().find('button').click()
```

but it did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next()` won't work in this case because the next element would be the text label with the date.

Instead, we can to use `.parent()` and `.siblings()` to move over to the other div and grab that button.

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Agile Fundamentals')
  .parent() // moves us to the div around the span
  .siblings('div') // moves us to the sibling div
  // could use `.next()` above instead
  .find('button') // moves us to the button
  // If you want to save this for ease of use, you can assign it an alias
  .as('dynamicButton')
  // and reference it like...
cy.get('@dynamicButton')...
```

Comment: Thanks for your super quick response and explaining in detail. Your suggested solution worked :) :)

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, change the target of `.contains()` to the card itself (the top level of that group of elements).

Starting from that element, `.find()` will get the button regardless of the nesting structure within the card.

```js
cy.contains('div.MuiCardHeader-root', 'Agile Fundamentals')
  .find('button')
  .click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to finding the button would be using the `aria-label` of the button. This will ONLY work if your DOM does not have another element with the same `aria-label` value.

```js
cy.get('[aria-label=settings]')
  .click()
```

If you there are other elements in the DOM that have matching attribute, then you can limit your search to the specific card

```js
cy.contains('.your-card-selector', /agile fundamentals/i)
  .find('[aria-label=settings]')
  .click()
```